# In a loop, is it better to redefine a global variable or to redeclare and redefine a local variable over and over, or is there no difference?

Tags: javascript, loops, global-variables, variable-declaration

For example:

is

```
for(var i = 1; i<100; i++){
  var inc = 1/i*PI;
  //and so forth
}
```

in any way better or worse than

```
var inc = 1/1*PI;
for(var i = 1; i<100; i++){
  inc = 1/i*PI;
}
```

Of course the first is easier to type, but maybe it takes away speed/performance (even if a little bit) from the program when constantly re-declaring the same variable versus reassigning values to a global variable. Thank you.

Comment: There's no need to initialise *inc* when declared in the second example since its value is set inside the loop anyway.

Comment: @RobG Right. I just put it there for no reason, but it helps when first seeing the variable declared to see what specific values it will hold in the program...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second approach is correct.  You should only declare variables once.

I would code your example like so:

```
var i,inc = 1/1*PI;
for(i = 1; i<100; i++){
  inc = 1/i*PI;
}
```

This puts all the variable declarations in one place which makes it easier to read the code.

If you would like to use block level scope, use the **let** statement, like so:

```
var i;
for(i = 1; i<100; i++){
  let inc = 1/i*PI;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Answer (score 1):

Because of `var` [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting), there is absolutely no difference between the two. And since it makes no difference, according to the docs:

> For that reason, it is recommended to always declare variables at the top of their scope (the top of global code and the top of function code) so it's clear which variables are function scoped (local) and which are resolved on the scope chain.

Now if you were using [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) instead of `var`, the story would be different. I don't think there would be any performance difference at all, but there would certainly then be a semantic difference. The documentation for `let` goes into detail about those differences.